# Post routing disambiguation based on content type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple WebAPI project in VS2012 using ASP.NET MVC 4. Here is what I am trying to do. I want to have two POST based actions taking the same url. I need one to accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and route to the method with `FormDataCollection` and then another action to be a no-content POST that routes to the other method. See the simplified code below.

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    public string Post(string x, int y, FormDataCollection data)
    {
        return "Post 1";
    }

    public string Post(string x, int y)
    {
        return "Post 2";
    }
```

}

Now when I try to post (2 calls, one with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the other with no content type or `text/plain`), I get internal server error (500) as the routing seems to get confused with similar methods. If I comment out either of the two, then the other one gets called in all scenarios.

Is this sort of fine routing supposed to be handled manually (regardless of how awkward it may appear) or is there something I am missing (like an attribute). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First, create the following class:

```
public class ButtonAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string ButtonName { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(ButtonName) != null;
    }
    public ButtonAttribute(string buttonName)
    {
        ButtonName = buttonName;
    }
}
```

Then, in the view, add the `name` attribute to your buttons:

```
<form action="~/Sample/Post" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="x" value="test" />
    <input type="number" name="y" value="123" />
    <input type="submit" value="First button" name="submit1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Second button" name="submit2" />
</form>
```

Finally, in you controller, add the `Button` attributes, as follows:

```
[Button("submit1")]
public string Post(string x, int y, FormDataCollection formData)
{
    return "Post 1";
}

[Button("submit2")]
public string Post(string x, int y)
{
    return "Post 2";
}
```